# How can I make my stickfigure jump using p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm just learning JavaScript in school and we need to build a game for an assignment. I'm starting of with drawing my main character and letting him walk right and left. Now, I want to let my main character jump everytime I press spacebar. Since I'm very new and can't find anything online, I thought I could shoot my shot here. This is what I have so far:

```
chX = 100;
chY = 250;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800,400);
  }
  
  function draw() {
    background("#0c3c5e");
    noStroke();
    fill("#466D1D");
    rect(0,300,800,100);
    mainCharacter(chX,chY);
    if(keyDown('LEFT_ARROW')){
        chX = chX - 1;
    }
    if(keyDown('RIGHT_ARROW')){
        chX = chX + 1;
    }

    
  }

  function mainCharacter(chX, chY){

    fill(255);
    stroke(0);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(chX, chY + 49, 20, 50); //lichaam
    circle(chX, chY, 50); //hoofd
    line(chX - 30, chY + 20, chX - 10, chY + 40); //arm links
    line(chX + 10, chY + 40, chX + 30, chY + 20); //arm rechts
    line(chX - 10, chY + 75, chX - 10, chY + 115); //been links
    line(chX - 10, chY + 75, chX - 10, chY + 115); //been rechts
    line(chX + 10, chY + 75, chX + 10, chY + 115); //been rechts
    strokeWeight(5);
    point(chX - 10, chY);
    point(chX + 10, chY);
  }
```

Can someone explain how I can make 'mainCharacter' jump? Or a reference to a website with some explanation? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is probably the easiest way:  *the numbers are basically just random also this is with a circle since it's a bit easier*

```
let x = 300, y = 200, groundY = 300
let yVel = 0, gravity = 5

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(20);
  
  if(y + 10 <= 300){ // if player.y + player.height < ground (if player is in the air)
    y += gravity     //                      radius*
  }
  
  y += yVel // y velocity
  yVel /= 1.2
  
  
  strokeWeight(16); stroke('lime')
  point(x, y)                        // the player
  
  strokeWeight(4); stroke('gold')
  line(0, groundY, width, groundY)   // the ground
}


function keyPressed(){ // only once on press of space bar (space bar in ascii is 32)
  if(y + 10 >= 300)
    if(keyCode == 32) // you could use && here
      yVel = -25
}
```

A jump is basically just:

- check if space bar is pressed
- check if player is in the air
- give player some upward velocity* "downward" here*
- if player is still in the air
- keep applying some gravity
- keep lessening player's velocity

also you can do acceleration to make everything smoother, but there's a bit more code, sooooooo, it should be just:

```
position += velocity
velocity += acceleration
```